# Ages in Genesis 5

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, parashat-bereishit, age

Are the life spans in Genesis 5 meant to be taken literally? Wasn't the life span of ancient people drastically shorter back then? I have read that the numbers are spiritual numbers that are used to represent an overall message, and not to be taken literally.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Henry, and thanks for the question (+1)! I edited the title to be a bit clearer, hope you don't mind. Hope to see you around. :)

Comment: If you can find meaning, that's great. Don't worry about if it actually happened or not.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4977/759 dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30/759

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4977, no? cc @DoubleAA

Comment: Note that since we date the calendar according to the years shown in the Torah, we appear to be taking it literally.